# Ошибка сервера 500 в LiveStreet

Tags: livestreet, cms

При установке движка на сервер возникает ошибка; после открытия главной (открывается нормально) при переходе на другой раздел возникает ошибка 500. Менял в файле Config.local.php с 1 на 0.

Comment: Скорее всего виноват кривой htaccess. Что написано в error log/access log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо изменить .htaccess файл лежащий в корне сайта:

Было

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php
```

Стало

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Теперь работает:) у меня.